# Constituency parse tree after processing

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I use Stanford CoreNLP to get constituency parse tree. I am wondering should I perform this after pre-processing or before pre-processing. In pre-processing I make the characters lower case, remove punctuations, remove stopwords (e.g., the, you're, ...) , remove numbers, keep just alphabets, and so on.

My task is getting a vector representation for each constituency parse tree by considering each leaf (i.e., token) as a vector embedding.

I am wondering how big the difference does it make if I get constituency parse tree after pre-processing?

Answer (score 0):

I would run the full pipeline without doing your custom processing.  The parser is trained on data that has not had your pre-processing applied to it.

Comment: Thanks. Then what do you think should I do with those tokens after parsing? I mean  regarding acquiring the vector representation of the entire parse tree by bottom-up parsing the tree